# Why is GDB so slow when I type I try to print an invalid symbol?

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, gdb

When I execute in GDB:

> p some_nonexistant_variable_name

GDB takes minutes (sometimes) to report that it can't find the the variable in scope.

Additionally when I type:

> p some_variable_that_is_in_scope->toString()

it takes forever...sometimes. Not sure why.

I'm using UBuntu 10.04, running GDB through Emacs 23. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this happening only under Emacs?  What happens if gdb is run from terminal or other places?

Comment: How big is the project? Is the output of `maintenance info symtabs` large?

Comment: `p some_variable_that_is_in_scope->toString()` --> Instead of accessing using member functions directly access the field irrespective of whether it's private or not. GDB will let you do that and it's bound to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think a recent release of gdb (6.5?) had a bug with searching large symbol tables, and a more recent one (6.7?) fixes it. Check out this [bug report](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9359) and see if it's relevant.